# Provide an array of origins to builder.WithOrigins in AddCors

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I thought there would already be an answer to this, but I could not find any.

I have a CORS setup like this, in my API server.

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
            builder.WithOrigins(AddCorsOrigin1LocalHost,
                                AddCorsOrigin2ProductionSite,
                                AddCorsOrigin3DevOrTestOrSomethingElseSite);
            builder.AllowAnyMethod();
            builder.AllowAnyHeader();
            builder.AllowCredentials();
        });
    });
```

I am adding the sites that I want, one by one, using a local string. This works as long as I only have 3 origins to use. I can keep changing the origins when I want.

However, if I have a 4th origin or more origins, I have to add a new local string and update it in the above code block.

I am curious, is there anyway, I can simply send a string collection of array or list. that way, when I have to add or remove origins, I could simply manipulate the string collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the sites in appsettings.json:

Here is a demo:

appsettings.json(I add Origins to it):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Origins": "http://example.com,http://www.contoso.com"
}
```

Startup.cs(change `Origins` to a string[]):

```
string[] s = Configuration["Origins"].Split(",");
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.WithOrigins(s);
                                  });
            });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: ah. looks neat. I will test it out and update here.

Comment: it works. and it also showed me how to use app settings for all kind of other values storage. very good.

Comment: Not working for me